# How is the Test Points calculated in 'Test PLan Progress' report of tfs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

How is the Test Points calculated in 'Test PLan Progress' report of tfs 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every configuration - test combination gets 1 point, so if you have 1 test that needs to be tested in 2 configuration, the report will show 2 test points.